# Вызов действия после запроса

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

Например, есть sql запрос INSERT. Как после удачного запроса вывести такой JS код

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.show-example').click(function () {
            var notice = 
                '<div class="notice">' + 
                '<div class="notice-body">' + 
                '<img src="./purr-example/info.png" alt=""/>' + 
                '<h3>Purr Example</h3>' + 
                '<p>This a normal Purr. It will fade out on its own.</p>' + 
                '</div>' + 
                '<div class="notice-bottom">' + 
                '</div>' + 
                '</div>';
            $(notice).purr({
                usingTransparentPNG: true
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Этот скрипт срабатывает по нажатию на ссылку с классом .show-example. А как сделать, чтобы весь функционал вызывался сам после того, как запрос прошел успешно.

Comment: Опишите подробнее метод отправления запроса.

Comment: Например 

    INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
если запрос выполнен то выполнить скрипт который я описал выше.
Я пытаюсь сделать всплывающие сообщения после удачного/не удачного запроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

мб запустить функцию-чекер успешного запроса в интервале?

например:

```
<script>
 function check() {
  if (...) { // условие успешного запроса
   var notice = 
            '<div class="notice">' + 
            '<div class="notice-body">' + 
            '<img src="./purr-example/info.png" alt=""/>' + 
            '<h3>Purr Example</h3>' + 
            '<p>This a normal Purr. It will fade out on its own.</p>' + 
            '</div>' + 
            '<div class="notice-bottom">' + 
            '</div>' + 
            '</div>';
        $(notice).purr({
            usingTransparentPNG: true
        });
  } else { setTimeout( function() { check(); }, 1000 ); }
 }
</script>
```

Если запрос идет через аякс:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "check.php",
   data: "mail=blabla@bla.ru",
   success: function(msg){
      if (msg != "0") {
          var notice = 
                '<div class="notice">' + 
                '<div class="notice-body">' + 
                '<img src="./purr-example/info.png" alt=""/>' + 
                '<h3>Purr Example</h3>' + 
                '<p>This a normal Purr. It will fade out on its own.</p>' + 
                '</div>' + 
                '<div class="notice-bottom">' + 
                '</div>' + 
                '</div>';
            $(notice).purr({
                usingTransparentPNG: true
            });
        }
   }
 });
```

где check.php:

```
$select = "SELECT email FROM users"; // в вашем случае здесь insert
$des = mysql_query($select) or die (mysql_error());
while($md = mysql_fetch_assoc($des)){
    if($md['email']===$email){echo "1";}
}
echo "0";
```